# how to get multiple command output as variable in awk

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, gawk

I am trying to execute 3 command and get the output as a variable which needs some percentage calculation and display the same as the example. can this be executed as script.

**First command output**

```
$ isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail"
Size:573T
Used:448.0T
Avail:74T
```

**Second command output**

```
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "\t\t\tSnapshot USED %=%.1f%%\n", $4}'
     Snapshot USED =0.6%
$ isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n -1 | awk '{ print "\t\t\tSnapshot USED:" $1}'
     Snapshot USED=3.2T
```

**example script** awk script not working. after removed space

```
# isi status -q | grep -e "^Size" -e "^Used" -e "^Avail" | awk 'function print (num)
pipe pipe quote> /Size:/ {TotalSize=$NF~}
pipe pipe quote> /Used:/ {TotalUsed=$NF}
pipe pipe quote> /Avail:/ {TotalAvail=$NF} }
pipe pipe quote> END {
pipe pipe quote>     used=TotalUsed/Total_Size*100
pipe pipe quote>     system("isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n -1 | awk '{ print "Snapshot_used=" $1}'")
pipe pipe quote>     system("isi_classic snapshot usage | tail -n 1 | awk '{printf "Snapshot_per :%.1f\n", $4}'")
pipe pipe quote>     Usedw/o=Total Used-Snapshot USED/Total Size
pipe pipe quote>     print hostname ": " "\t","Total Size:" Total_Size
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tTotalUsed:%.1f\n", TotalUsed, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tTotalAvail:%.1f\n", TotalAvail, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tTotalUsed %:%.1f\n", used, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tSnapshot Used :%.1f\n", Snapshot_used, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tSnapshot Used %:%.1f\n", Snapshot_per, "TB"
pipe pipe quote>     printf "\t\t\tUsed w/o:%.1f\n", Usedw/o, TB)'
awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
        function >>>  print <<<  (num)
        missing }
        missing )
awk: bailing out at source line 7
```

**Sample Requirement**

```
Total Size      : 573 TB
Total Used      : 448.0 TB
Total Available : 74 TB
Total Used %    : 86.1 %   # Total Used(%) = Total Used/Total Size *100 = 86.1(%)
Snapshot Used   : 3.2 TB
Snapshot Used % : 0.6 %
Used w/o        : 85.5 %    # {(Total used)-(Snapshot used)} / (Total size) = 85.49%
```

Comment: You cannot have _space_ in variable name, please remove all spaces like `TotalSize` in `Total Size=$NF~` (what is `~` here?!) and all others and in printf statements as well.

Comment: @αғsнιηHave tried with removing the space still its not working. I have edited the question.

Comment: Its not taking the function num.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer:

```
Totalanswer=$(command1 ; command2)
Subanswer1=$(echo $Totalanswer|grep Sub1)
Subanswer2=$(echo $Totalanswer|grep Sub2)
printf " Answer1:%s\n Answer2:%s\n" $Subanswer1 $SubAnswer2
```

Added comment:
The trick is in getting the required information by using the right tools. Using an external (ie. no native shell) command is to be avoided. Replacing the greps with bash native ([hint](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#common_use)) is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It is not really a code snippet sharing site. I think we should share *knowledge* and not scripts for copy-paste. I suggest to share the *knowledge* what made you possible to write this script, this is the important and not the script (although having also the script, beside the explanation, is obviously useful).